# Tar restore syntax to only restore UNhidden files

Tags: tar, restore

What is the proper syntax for only restoring files that are NOT hidden?  I'd like to copy those by hand, as needed, without bulk overwriting anything that's already there.  So for example, I'd like to ignore the .thumbnails, .cache, .config, etc. but copy everything else.  I've tried:

```
tar zxvf --exclude=.* mybackup.tar.gz
```

But this didn't work.  Any suggestions?  Or does this only happen on the backup side, and restore is stuck restoring whatever was tarred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the --exclude parameter first and also you must put quotes around the pattern for files you are excluding:

```
tar --exclude='.*' -zxvf mybackup.tar.gz
```